# Malformed JSON: Expected '{' at the beginning of object for the LIST

Tags: apex, apexrest

I am making an endpoint call and trying to extract the value from JSON.I am getting the parser error. What I am doing wrong here?

**Apex controller**

```
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint(url);
req.setMethod('GET');

HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
System.debug('@@response--->' +res.getBody());
String jsonStr = res.getBody();
Map <String,Object > resultsMap = (Map < String, Object > ) JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody()); 
List<Object> offList = (List<Object>)resultsMap.get('resultsets');
String JSONString = JSON.serialize(offList);
System.debug('@@@json==>'+JSONString);

PDS_FindDentalOfficeTypes off = PDS_FindDentalOfficeTypes.parse(JSONString);
```

**Type class**

```
    public class PDS_FindDentalOfficeTypes {

    public class Results {
        public String title;
        public String OfficeNumber;
        public String Name;
        public String AddressLine1;
        public String AddressLine2;
        public String AddressLine3;
        public String City;
        public String State;
        public String ZipCode;
        public String Latitude;
        public String Longitude;
        public String location;
        public String PrimaryPhoneNumber;
        public String Thumbnail;
        public String Rating;
        public String ReviewNumber;
        public String OpenDate;
        public String DaysOld;
        public String NewlyOpened;
        public String AvailableService;
        public String PrimaryDomainName;
        public String ExpansionOffice;
        public String MyKidsDentist;
        public String OfficeDetailPath;
    }

    public String name;
    public List<Results> results;


    public static PDS_FindDentalOfficeTypes parse(String json) {
        return (PDS_FindDentalOfficeTypes) System.JSON.deserializeStrict(json, PDS_FindDentalOfficeTypes.class);
    }
}
```

**JSON***

```
22:15:16.0 (260844352)|USER_DEBUG|[62]|DEBUG|@@@json==>[{"results":[{"OfficeDetailPath":"/92614/11-The Dental Office on Red Hill","MyKidsDentist":"","ExpansionOffice":"false","PrimaryDomainName":"www.DentalOfficeOnRedHill.com","AvailableService":"Crowns&#124;Fillings&#124;Hygiene&#124;Implants&#124;Periodontics&#124;Endodontics&#124;Veneers&#124;TeethWhitening&#124;OralSurgery&#124;Emergency&#124;","NewlyOpened":"false","DaysOld":"2087","OpenDate":"Mon, 07 Oct 2013 00:00:00 GMT","ReviewNumber":"421","Rating":"4","Thumbnail":"http://www.1.smilegeneration.com/uploadedimages/Office/11/exterior_small.jpg","PrimaryPhoneNumber":"949-975-0150","location":"+33.6987-117.8486","Longitude":"-117.848675","Latitude":"33.698713","ZipCode":"92614","State":"CA","City":"Irvine","AddressLine3":"","AddressLine2":"Ste D","AddressLine1":"17010 Red Hill Ave","Name":"The Dental Office on Red Hill","OfficeNumber":"11","title":""}],"name":"default"}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have received a `List<PDS_FindDentalOfficeTypes>` rather than a single instance. So deserialize into the collection instead:

```
List<MyWrapper> data = (List<MyWrapper>)JSON.deserializeStrict(payload, List<MyWrapper>.class);
```